# "https://rubygems.org" is not allowed by the gemspec, which only allows "'http://rubygems.org'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to compile my first gem and push it to rubygems.org. It keeps throwing an error saying I can't push to https://rubygems.org:

```
gem build simplesms.gemspec 
WARNING:  licenses is empty, but is recommended.  Use a license identifier from
http://spdx.org/licenses or 'Nonstandard' for a nonstandard license.
WARNING:  no homepage specified
WARNING:  See http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/ for help
  Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: simplesms
  Version: 0.1.0
  File: simplesms-0.1.0.gem
Toms-MacBook-Pro-2:simplesms t$ gem push simplesms-0.1.0.gem 
Pushing gem to https://rubygems.org...
ERROR:  "https://rubygems.org" is not allowed by the gemspec, which only allows "'http://rubygems.org'"
```

But in my spec:

```
# coding: utf-8
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'simplesms/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "simplesms"
  spec.version       = Simplesms::VERSION
  spec.authors       = ["Tom"]
  spec.email         = ["tom@example.com"]

  spec.summary       = %q{Easily add sms to your project by integrating the Simple SMS Heroku Addon into your app.}
  spec.homepage      = ""

  # Prevent pushing this gem to RubyGems.org. To allow pushes either set the 'allowed_push_host'
  # to allow pushing to a single host or delete this section to allow pushing to any host.
  if spec.respond_to?(:metadata)
    spec.metadata['allowed_push_host'] = "'http://rubygems.org'"
  else
    raise "RubyGems 2.0 or newer is required to protect against public gem pushes."
  end

  spec.files         = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").reject { |f| f.match(%r{^(test|spec|features)/}) }
  spec.bindir        = "exe"
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^exe/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.12"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 10.0"
end
```

In the gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

# Specify your gem's dependencies in simplesms.gemspec
gemspec
```

Just for kicks I also tried setting them to 'https://rubygems.org', however it still throws the same error.

Any idea what I need to do to get this to push to rubygems.org? I already signed in with my email/password and confirmed the credentials are in `~/.gem/credentials`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line:

```
spec.metadata['allowed_push_host'] = "'http://rubygems.org'"
```

You're setting `allowed_push_host` to `'http://rubygems.org'`. It should just be `http://rubygems.org` (without the single quotes). Change it to:

```
spec.metadata['allowed_push_host'] = "http://rubygems.org"
```

It should be safe (and preferred) to allow `https://rubygems.org` instead, too.

Comment: I swear I tried that! But it worked like a charm! Thanks :)